# Gamma function and factorial

Tags: real-analysis, factorial, gamma-function

The gamma function is defined by

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt.$$
What made the mathematicians define it like this instead of
$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z}e^{-t}dt.$$
This would make the gamma function a "real" generalization of the factorial function $\Gamma(n)=n!$

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1) math overflow question.

Comment: @PeterForeman  Thanks, the mathematical community should do something about this, it's irritating :)

Comment: There are several questions about that on MSE as well, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18356/why-isnt-the-gamma-function-defined-so-that-gamman-n).

Comment: You might want to listen to this one
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CO6IZtCMpjk

Comment: The notation was introduced by Legendre and he used a different integral (but equivalent) to introduce it. You might want to have a look at A. M. Legendre, Exercises de Calcul Intégral (1811), p. 277.